# Is it possible to render a .blend file without blender being installed?

Tags: python, blender

I want to create a python program that takes a .blend file and renders it without blender being installed.

is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

A `.blend` is just a `.zip` with assets inside (model definitios, normals, textures, ...)  So yea, you could change the extension, extract usable potions, then display it with another app.

It would be up you to figure out how to parse & piece together those things...  I'd just export it in an open format that's easier to find a viewer for, like `.obj` or .`stl`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

---

You might have some luck with this, don't think it does textures tho.

https://github.com/gabdube/tinyblend

Comment: It is wildly inaccurate to say that .blend files are just a .zip files. The format is completely different and changing the extension would not yield anything useful. It is a custom binary file format.